# These policy alternatives can not be satisifed

Tags: soap, soapui, policy

So I am trying to test a SOAP endpoint with SoapUI.

This is how my SOAP request looks like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <o:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-6a13a244-dac6-42c1-84c5-cbb345b0c4c4-1">
            <o:Username>username</o:Username>
            <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:RequestSecurityToken Context="?">
         <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
      </ns:RequestSecurityToken>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I keep getting this response

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:MustUnderstand</faultcode>
         <faultstring>MustUnderstand headers: [{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood.</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If I change the value of `mustUnderstand` to 0, it gives this error

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/}SupportingTokens
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/}UsernameToken</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My security policy looks like below:

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
            wsu:Id="UserNameWSTrustBinding_IWSTrust13Async_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken
                            sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy></wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:UsernameToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SupportingTokens>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Not sure what I am missing now. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. We were not using `org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security` and `org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy` jars. I will write a post to explain this in detail.

Comment: and? did you write the post?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you wrote that article?

Comment: I did. Let me know if this helps https://betterjavacode.com/programming/how-to-add-soap-headers-to-request-response

Comment: having the same issue and both jars are included. Are you sure that this was causing the issue?